# Reducing $2018^{2018}\pmod6$ via $\mod2$ and $\mod3$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

I've been tasked to reduce $$2018^{2018}\pmod6$$using the results of reducing$$2018^{2018}\pmod2$$and $$2018^{2018}\pmod3$$

---

I have deduced that $$2018^{2018}\equiv0\pmod2$$and $$2018^{2018}\equiv1\pmod3$$but I don't see a way to combine these two congruences into one $\mod6$ congruence. Could someone tell me how this is achieved? I have a feeling the answer is really simple, but I just don't see it. Is there also a more generalized strategy of solving modular congruences via the divisors of the modulo number($2$ and $3$ are divisors of $6$)?

---

The way I have currently solved this problem is to first reduce $$2018^{2018}\pmod6$$ to $$2^{2018}\pmod6$$Then we look for patterns:$$\begin{align}2^1&\equiv2\pmod6\\2^2&\equiv4\pmod6\\2^3&\equiv2\pmod6\\2^4&\equiv4\pmod6\\&\ \ .\\&\ \ .\\&\ \ .\\2^n&\equiv\begin{cases}4&\text{if }n\equiv0\pmod2\\2&\text{if }n\equiv1\pmod2\end{cases}\pmod6\end{align}$$for $n\in\Bbb N$. In the case of $2018^{2018}$, $2018\equiv0\pmod2$, so $$2018^{2018}\equiv2^{2018}\equiv4\pmod6$$

Comment: check the chinese remainder theorem, it is exactly the tool you need here

Comment: @ALakatos After looking through the Wikipedia page for Chinese Remainder Theorem, I still don't really understand how I can use it to solve this congruence. The level of math in the Wikipedia page is just a tad too high for me.

Comment: It’s nothing but looking for a number between $0$ and $5$ inclusive that’s $\equiv0\pmod2$ and $\equiv1\pmod3$. Just check them all, and you see that your answer is…

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=2018^{2018}$. The Chinese Remainder theorem tells us that given that 2 and 3 are coprime. Then the system $$\begin{cases}
x = 0\ (mod\ 2)\\
x = 1\ (mod\ 3)\\
\end{cases}$$
has an unique solution $mod(2*3) = mod(6)$. Note that you can easily check that 4 is the only number that is congruent to $0\ (mod\ 2)$ and $1\ (mod\ 3)$ (between 0 and 5). Therefore, that is the unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I have deduced that $2018^{2018}\equiv0\pmod2$ and $2018^{2018}\equiv1\pmod3$, but I don't see a way to combine these two congruences into one $\bmod6$ congruence

One way that works in this situation

(besides trial and error and construction, which others have mentioned)

is to note that this is the constant case of the Chinese remainder theorem:

$x\equiv0\bmod2$ and $x\equiv1\bmod3 \iff x\equiv-2\bmod2$ and $x\equiv-2\bmod3$

$\iff  x\equiv-2\bmod6 \iff x\equiv4\bmod6$.

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese remainder theorem states that, for these congruence equations:

$$
x\equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
x\equiv1\pmod 3
$$

Then different solutions of $x$ are congruent mod $6$, that is, $x_1 \equiv x_2 \pmod 6$.

You have calculated $2018^{2018} \bmod 2$ and $2018^{2018} \bmod 3$, and know that $x_1 = 2018^{2018}$ is a solution.

By trial and error for all the integers $0,1, \cdots, 6-1$, or by [direct construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Using_the_existence_construction), $x_2 = 4$ is another solution. So

$$2018^{2018} \equiv 4 \pmod 6$$

Comment: So to generalize, if I were solving $x\pmod y$, I would first find $x\pmod {k_1}$ and $x\pmod {k_2}$, where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are coprime divisors of $y$, then look for an integer between $0$ and $y-1$ inclusive that is congruent to both $x\pmod {k_1}$ and $x\pmod {k_2}$?

Comment: @AidenChow Yes ($k_1$ and $k_2$ are not just coprime divisors of $y$, but also $k_1k_2 = y$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=2018^{2018},$ then

$$ \qquad\qquad x\equiv (-1)^{2018}\equiv 1 \quad  \pmod 3 \tag*{(1)}$$
$$ x\equiv 0 \quad  \pmod 2 \tag*{(2)} $$
From $(1)$, we have $(*):x=3m+1$ for some integer $m$. Then putting $x$ into $(2)$ yields $$ \begin{aligned} & \quad  3m+1\equiv 0 \quad  \pmod 2\\\Leftrightarrow & \quad  m\equiv 1 \quad  \pmod 2 \\\Leftrightarrow &  \quad  m=2n+1 \textrm{ for some integer }n \end{aligned}$$
Putting back to (*) conclude that $$x=3(2n+1)+1\equiv 4 \quad  \pmod 6.$$